# Python: Get all values of a specific key from json file

Tags: python, json

Im getting the json data from a file:

```
 "students": [
     {
        "name" : "ben",
        "age" : 15
     },
     {
        "name" : "sam",
        "age" : 14
     }
  ]
}
```

here's my initial code:

```
def get_names():
  students = open('students.json')
  data = json.load(students)
```

I want to get the values of all names

```
[ben,sam]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to extract the names from the `students` list.

```py
data = {"students": [
     {
        "name" : "ben",
        "age" : 15
     },
     {
        "name" : "sam",
        "age" : 14
     }
  ]
       }

names = [each_student['name'] for each_student in data['students']]

print(names) #['ben', 'sam']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a list comprehension:

```
>>> [dct['name'] for dct in data['students']]
['ben', 'sam']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
with open('./students.json', 'r') as students_file:
    students_content = json.load(students_file)
print([student['name'] for student in students_content['students']]) # ['ben', 'sam']
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

JSON's load function from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html):

> Deserialize fp (a .read()-supporting text file or binary file containing a JSON document) to a Python object...

The JSON file in students.json will look like:

```
{
    "students": [
        {
        "name" : "ben",
        "age" : 15
        },
        {
        "name" : "sam",
        "age" : 14
        }
    ]
}
```

The JSON load function can then be used to deserialize this JSON object in the file to a Python dictionary:

```py
import json

# use with context manager to ensure the file closes properly
with open('students.json', 'rb')as students_fp:
    data = json.load(students_fp)

print(type(data))  # dict i.e. a Python dictionary

# list comprehension to take the name of each student
names = [student['name'] for student in data['students']]
```

Where names now contains the desired:

```py
["ben", "sam"]
```